# Jenkins and Maven Failing mvn assembly

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

My Jenkins project runs mvn assembly:single and it fails without a clear error. I can run it in the workspace on cmd (Windows) and it works fine. I increased the memory using MAVEN_OPTS -Xmx10240m -Xss1024m but it didn't seem to affect anything.

Each job fails with a slightly different error, always a stackoverflowError but with a different string related function. I noticed that when I download the consoleText of each job and they are all 2.5 MB but I'm not sure if thats related.

Example errors below. All of them are identical, so I truncated a few, but note it fails at a different dependency and shows a slightly different error:

```
[INFO] com/microsoft/applicationinsights/core/dependencies/google/api/SystemParametersOrBuilder.class already added, skipping
[INFO] com/microsoft/applicationinsights/core/dependencies/google/api/DocumentationOrBuilder.class already added, skipping
[[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  40.030 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-03-07T13:04:16-08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------
constituent[0]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin/../conf/logging/
constituent[1]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin/../lib/animal-sniffer-annotations-1.14.jar
constituent[2]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin/../lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar
constituent[3]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin/../lib/cdi-api-1.0.jar
constituent[4]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin/../lib/checker-compat-qual-2.0.0.jar
constituent[5]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin/../lib/commons-cli-1.4.jar
constituent[6]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin/../lib/commons-io-2.5.jar
constituent[7]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin/../lib/commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar
constituent[8]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin/../lib/error_prone_annotations-2.1.3.jar
constituent[9]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin/../lib/guava-25.1-android.jar
constituent[10]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin/../lib/guice-4.2.1-no_aop.jar
constituent[11]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin/../lib/j2objc-annotations-1.1.jar
constituent[12]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin/../lib/jansi-1.17.1.jar
constituent[13]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin/../lib/javax.inject-1.jar
constituent[14]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin/../lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar
constituent[15]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin/../lib/jsr250-api-1.0.jar
constituent[16]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin/../lib/jsr305-3.0.2.jar
constituent[17]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin/../lib/maven-artifact-3.6.0.jar
constituent[18]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin/../lib/maven-builder-support-3.6.0.jar
constituent[19]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin/../lib/maven-compat-3.6.0.jar
constituent[20]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin/../lib/maven-core-3.6.0.jar
constituent[21]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin/../lib/maven-embedder-3.6.0.jar
constituent[22]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin/../lib/maven-model-3.6.0.jar
constituent[23]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin/../lib/maven-model-builder-3.6.0.jar
constituent[24]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin/../lib/maven-plugin-api-3.6.0.jar
constituent[25]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin/../lib/maven-repository-metadata-3.6.0.jar
constituent[26]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin/../lib/maven-resolver-api-1.3.1.jar
constituent[27]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin/../lib/maven-resolver-connector-basic-1.3.1.jar
constituent[28]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin/../lib/maven-resolver-impl-1.3.1.jar
constituent[29]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin/../lib/maven-resolver-provider-3.6.0.jar
constituent[30]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin/../lib/maven-resolver-spi-1.3.1.jar
constituent[31]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin/../lib/maven-resolver-transport-wagon-1.3.1.jar
constituent[32]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin/../lib/maven-resolver-util-1.3.1.jar
constituent[33]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin/../lib/maven-settings-3.6.0.jar
constituent[34]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin/../lib/maven-settings-builder-3.6.0.jar
constituent[35]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin/../lib/maven-shared-utils-3.2.1.jar
constituent[36]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin/../lib/maven-slf4j-provider-3.6.0.jar
constituent[37]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin/../lib/org.eclipse.sisu.inject-0.3.3.jar
constituent[38]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin/../lib/org.eclipse.sisu.plexus-0.3.3.jar
constituent[39]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin/../lib/plexus-cipher-1.7.jar
constituent[40]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin/../lib/plexus-component-annotations-1.7.1.jar
constituent[41]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin/../lib/plexus-interpolation-1.25.jar
constituent[42]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin/../lib/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.4.jar
constituent[43]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin/../lib/plexus-utils-3.1.0.jar
constituent[44]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin/../lib/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar
constituent[45]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin/../lib/wagon-file-3.2.0.jar
constituent[46]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin/../lib/wagon-http-3.2.0-shaded.jar
constituent[47]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin/../lib/wagon-provider-api-3.2.0.jar
---------------------------------------------------
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:526)
at java.io.PrintStream.print(PrintStream.java:583)
at org.fusesource.jansi.FilterPrintStream.write(FilterPrintStream.java:99)
at org.fusesource.jansi.FilterPrintStream.write(FilterPrintStream.java:107)
at org.fusesource.jansi.FilterPrintStream.print(FilterPrintStream.java:156)
at org.fusesource.jansi.FilterPrintStream.println(FilterPrintStream.java:231)
at org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLogger.write(SimpleLogger.java:318)
at org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLogger.log(SimpleLogger.java:295)
at org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLogger.info(SimpleLogger.java:480)
at org.apache.maven.cli.logging.Slf4jLogger.info(Slf4jLogger.java:59)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:464)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
```

Note: org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext is repeated for about 500 lines

```
[INFO] com/microsoft/applicationinsights/core/dependencies/google/api/LogDescriptorOrBuilder.class already added, skipping
[INFO] com/microsoft/applicationinsights/core/dependencies/google/api/ExperimentalProto$1.class already added, skipping
[[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
....................
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
at org.fusesource.jansi.Ansi._appendEscapeSequence(Ansi.java:768)
at org.fusesource.jansi.Ansi.flushAttributes(Ansi.java:754)
at org.fusesource.jansi.Ansi.a(Ansi.java:596)
at org.apache.maven.shared.utils.logging.AnsiMessageBuilder.info(AnsiMessageBuilder.java:60)
at org.slf4j.impl.MavenSimpleLogger.renderLevel(MavenSimpleLogger.java:50)
at org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLogger.log(SimpleLogger.java:277)
at org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLogger.info(SimpleLogger.java:480)
at org.apache.maven.cli.logging.Slf4jLogger.info(Slf4jLogger.java:59)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:464)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)


[INFO] com/microsoft/applicationinsights/core/dependencies/google/api/OAuthRequirements$1.class already added, skipping
[INFO] com/microsoft/applicationinsights/core/dependencies/google/api/MonitoredResource$LabelsDefaultEntryHolder.class already added, skipping
[[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
....................
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at sun.nio.cs.SingleByte.withResult(SingleByte.java:44)
at sun.nio.cs.SingleByte.access$000(SingleByte.java:38)
at sun.nio.cs.SingleByte$Encoder.encodeArrayLoop(SingleByte.java:187)
at sun.nio.cs.SingleByte$Encoder.encodeLoop(SingleByte.java:219)
at java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder.encode(CharsetEncoder.java:579)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:271)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:125)
at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:207)
at java.io.BufferedWriter.flushBuffer(BufferedWriter.java:129)
at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:526)
at java.io.PrintStream.print(PrintStream.java:583)
at org.fusesource.jansi.FilterPrintStream.write(FilterPrintStream.java:99)
at org.fusesource.jansi.FilterPrintStream.write(FilterPrintStream.java:107)
at org.fusesource.jansi.FilterPrintStream.print(FilterPrintStream.java:156)
at org.fusesource.jansi.FilterPrintStream.println(FilterPrintStream.java:231)
at org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLogger.write(SimpleLogger.java:318)
at org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLogger.log(SimpleLogger.java:295)
at org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLogger.info(SimpleLogger.java:480)
at org.apache.maven.cli.logging.Slf4jLogger.info(Slf4jLogger.java:59)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:464)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)


[INFO] com/microsoft/applicationinsights/core/dependencies/google/api/ExperimentalProto$1.class already added, skipping
[INFO] com/microsoft/applicationinsights/core/dependencies/google/api/AuthorizationConfigOrBuilder.class already added, skipping
[[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
....................
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:326)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:482)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:104)
at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flushBuffer(OutputStreamWriter.java:185)
at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:527)
at java.io.PrintStream.print(PrintStream.java:583)
at org.fusesource.jansi.FilterPrintStream.write(FilterPrintStream.java:99)
at org.fusesource.jansi.FilterPrintStream.write(FilterPrintStream.java:107)
at org.fusesource.jansi.FilterPrintStream.print(FilterPrintStream.java:156)
at org.fusesource.jansi.FilterPrintStream.println(FilterPrintStream.java:231)
at org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLogger.write(SimpleLogger.java:318)
at org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLogger.log(SimpleLogger.java:295)
at org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLogger.info(SimpleLogger.java:480)
at org.apache.maven.cli.logging.Slf4jLogger.info(Slf4jLogger.java:59)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:464)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
```

Comment: You should not call `mvn assembly:single` it's better to use the creation of the archive during the package life cycle...Apart from that you haven't define the version for maven-assembly-plugin in your pom cause I suppose you are using an old version of maven-assembly-plugin...

Comment: Yes, it was an old version. I specified a newer version and it appears to be working.